# How do you count consecutive strings in file using powershell?

Tags: powershell, count, unique, uniq

So I want to know how I could get content from a file and count the consecutive occurrences of a string within that file?
So my file has the following strings:

```
1
1
1
0
0
0
0
1
1
1
0
1
1
0
0
0
1
0
1
1
1
0
0
```

Now the thing is I know next to nothing about powershell, but know bash, so if somebody understands both, this is my desired effect:

```
[me@myplace aaa8]$ cat fule1|uniq -c
      3 1
      4 0
      3 1
      1 0
      2 1
      3 0
      1 1
      1 0
      3 1
      2 0
```

And if it's possible, also add the powershell equivalent of `sort -hr` :D

```
[me@myplace aaa8]$ cat fule1|uniq -c|sort -hr
      4 0
      3 1
      3 1
      3 1
      3 0
      2 1
      2 0
      1 1
      1 0
      1 0
```

So basically what this does is it tells me that the file I had has the longest streak of 4 zeroes, etc.

Is there a way to do this with powershell?

Comment: Could be something like that: `[regex]::Matches('aaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbccc', '(.)\1+').Groups | Where-Object { $_.Length -gt 1 }  | Sort-Object -Unique -Property Value` combined with `[RegexOptions]::Multiline` option for your task. `Measure-Object` command might be useful too. I'm not sure about your input data size and how fast regular expressions will work.

Comment: @Rabash: `uniq -c` doesn't exclude single instances, so your solution won't work. In general, future readers benefit most from full-fledged answers, not (half-)solutions in comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PowerShell's equivalent to the `uniq` utility, the [`Get-Unique` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-unique), unfortunately has no equivalent to the former's `-c` option** for prepending the number of *consecutive* duplicate lines (as of PowerShell v6.2).

<sup>Note: Enhancing `Get-Unique` to support a `-c`-like feature and other features offered by the [`uniq` POSIX utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/uniq.html) is the subject of this [feature request on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9217).</sup>

Therefore, you must **roll your own solution**:

```
function Get-UniqueWithCount {

  begin {
    $instanceCount = 1; $prevLine = $null
  }

  process {
    if ($_ -eq $prevLine) {
      ++$instanceCount
    } elseif ($null -ne $prevLine) {
      [pscustomobject] @{ InstanceCount = $instanceCount; Line = $prevLine }
      $instanceCount = 1
    }
    $prevLine = $_
  }

  end {
    [pscustomobject] @{ InstanceCount = $instanceCount; Line = $prevLine }
  }

}
```

The above function accepts input from the pipeline (object by object as  `$_` in the `process { ... }` block).
It compares each object (line) to the previous one and, if they're equal, increments the instance count; once a different line is found, the previous line is output, along with its instance count, *as an object* with properties `InstanceCount` and `Line`. The `end { ... }` block outputs the final output object for the last block of identical consecutive lines.
See [about_Functions_Advanced](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced).

Then invoke it as follows:

```
Get-Content fule | Get-UniqueWithCount
```

which yields:

```
InstanceCount Line
------------- ----
            3 1
            4 0
            3 1
            1 0
            2 1
            3 0
            1 1
            1 0
            3 1
            2 0
```

Since `Get-UniqueWithCount` conveniently outputs *objects* whose *typed* *properties* we can act on, the equivalent of `sort -hr` (sort by embedded numbers (`-h`), in descending (reverse) order (`-r`)) is easy:

```
Get-Content fule | Get-UniqueWithCount | Sort-Object -Descending InstanceCount
```

which yields:

```
InstanceCount Line
------------- ----
            4 0
            3 1
            3 1
            3 0
            3 1
            2 1
            2 0
            1 0
            1 1
            1 0
```